# Add id to element based on element length by jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="span_group">
<span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
<span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
<span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
<span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
<span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
</div>
$(".span_group .sp_main span").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("id","span"+$(this).children("span").length); 
});
```

Iam trying to add id="span+length" to child span of 
expected output is like below

```
<span class="sp_main"><span id="span1">Sample text</span></span>
<span class="sp_main"><span id="span2">Sample text</span></span>
<span class="sp_main"><span id="span3">Sample text</span></span>...
```

Please help

Comment: So what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to generate the `id` based on the parent(`.sp_main`) element's index(based on the siblings)

```js
$(".span_group .sp_main span").attr('id', function(index) {
  return "span" + ($(this).parent().index() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span_group">
  <span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
  <span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
  <span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
  <span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
  <span class="sp_main"><span>Sample text</span></span>
</div>
```